# Disabling scroll on listview when list has scrolled to its end

Tags: android, listview

I want to disable scroll to upside when list scrolls to end already or disable scroll to down when listscrolls to top already due to some issues in list view. Issue is when i try to scroll it more(when list is already scrolled to end) it will show second last entry again and show scrolling again.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ActivateDetailTicketFooterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VisitorEntity>
{
    Context context;
    int id;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<VisitorEntity> list;
    View v;
    VisitorEntity entity;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String status;

    public ActivateDetailTicketFooterAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<VisitorEntity> objects, String status) { 
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        this.list = objects;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
        this.status = status;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView age, gender, passNo, edit;
        ImageView image;
        LinearLayout parentRowLl, passdeactivatedLl,parent;
    }

    public void setViewHolder(ViewHolder holder){
        holder.parent=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        holder.age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.age);
        holder.gender = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        holder.passNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pass_no);
        holder.edit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);     
        holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.parentRowLl = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.parent_row);
        holder.passdeactivatedLl = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pass_deactivated);


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        v = convertView;
        entity = list.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null){



            v = inflater.inflate(id, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            setViewHolder(holder); 
        }  
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        /*v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }*/
        if (holder!=null) {


        String pass_no = entity.getPassNo();
        pass_no = pass_no.substring(pass_no.lastIndexOf("/")+1, pass_no.length());
        holder.age.setText("Age: "+entity.getAge());
        holder.gender.setText("Gender: "+entity.getGender());
        holder.passNo.setText("Pass no: "+pass_no);
        //String name = entity.getImage().trim();
        //name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1, name.length());
        if (entity.getImage().contains("no_upload")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.demo_normal);  
            entity.setIsDemo("yes");
        }
        else {
            imageLoader.displayListingImage(entity.getImage(), holder.image, "0");
            entity.setIsDemo("no");
        }



        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("completed")){
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.image.setTag(entity.getImage());
        if(entity.getIsPassDeactivated().equals("1")){
            holder.passdeactivatedLl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.passdeactivatedLl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        holder.edit.setTag(position);
        holder.parentRowLl.setTag(position);
        holder.parentRowLl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!status.equalsIgnoreCase("completed")){
                    int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditCustomerDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("age", list.get(pos).getAge());
                    intent.putExtra("gender", list.get(pos).getGender());
                    intent.putExtra("passno", list.get(pos).getPassNo());
                    intent.putExtra("image", list.get(pos).getImage());
                    SoapConstants.imageUrl=list.get(0).getImage();
                    intent.putExtra("visitorId", list.get(pos).getVisitorId());
                    intent.putExtra("passdeactivated", list.get(pos).getIsPassDeactivated());
                    intent.putExtra("museumName", list.get(pos).getMuseumName());
                    intent.putExtra("listPosition",pos+"");


                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(list.get(position).getIsDemo().equals("no")){
                    String image = (String) v.getTag();
                    if (image.contains("http://")) {
                        image = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf("/")+1, image.length());
                    }

                    showImage(image);
                }
            }
        });
        /*android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp=holder.parent.getLayoutParams();
        SoapConstants.visistorListHeight=lp.height;*/
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void showImage(String image){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_dialog);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ((Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.done_btn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        if (image.contains(SoapConstants.imageUrlForDefault)|| image.contains(SoapConstants.imageUrlForDefault1)) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.demovsitormedium);
        }
        else {
            Bitmap bm = imageLoader.getImageFromLocal(image,true);

            if (bm!=null) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
            else {
                image=image.replace("_big", "");
                Bitmap bm1 = imageLoader.getImageFromLocal(image,false);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            }
        }
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: unable to understand.... :(

Comment: disabling scroll on list after scrolling to end.

Comment: r u using endlessadapter ?i mean loadmore functionality ?

Comment: No its coustom adapter